# Dynamic uitableviewcell height is wrong after using edit mode & reloadSections

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

When I delete a cell in edit mode and use reloadsections to update the tableview, the cell size is too high. I use a custom cell but strangely the same thing happens with the standard 'subtitle' cell style. It doesn't happen with reloadData. I prefer to use reloadSections for the animation.

```
 [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

[image: left: correct -- right: wrong]

[image]
Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Probably you have not enough constrains? Have you specified space above the title, between title and url, and below url?

Comment: Looking at your constraints you're missing one between the two labels. The title top should be pinned to superview, the bottom should be pinned to the top of the URL, and the URL bottom should be pinned to the superview.

Comment: I think I did what you said. This is what I have now: http://i.imgur.com/jNnxYnT.png
It still happens occasionally.